# Hosting Javascript/CSS file on CDN similar to Google hosting jQuery

Tags: cdn

I am wondering if there are any hosts or if I can host my file (JS & CSS) on Google so that they are cached and load real quick (due to CDN and gzip).

A number of my customers use these files and I would prefer if they could somehow include this to file to receive the JS file. Ideally with filename.js?publickey=sdfgsdfg (which will be tied to a particular domain name).

The problem is that my hosting needs are very small- only about 100kb.

Any suggestions? My problem is that the customers using the JS & CSS file, have no clue about gzipping content or caching (as their shared hosts do not support it), as a result causes the JS/CSS to take forever to load. Am wondering if I can leverage an existing free service, or I do not mind paying either.

Comment: Is it worth changing the accepted answer now? Seeing as SimpleCDN is no longer around and @Vnuk is getting hit with downvotes for something that isn't their fault?

Answer (score -16, accepted):

Try [SimpleCDN](http://www.simplecdn.com/). You can store your files very cheap and the traffic is also not that expensive. Number of people have complained to their service - I have no objections.

Comment: SimpleCDN is no longer in business.

Comment: It's kinda hard not to notice when your cdn provider goes bust and takes your prepaid credits with them :D

Answer (score 4):

[CDNJS.com](http://www.cdnjs.com/) allows you to submit a pull request to their [GitHub](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs) account to get a JavaScript library on their CDN.  I've been attempting to get a CSS library added on <del>[their forum](http://cdnjs.uservoice.com/forums/98277-general/suggestions/1971479)</del> old and abandoned forum.

Answer (score 3):

If you're comfortable with the Amazon cloud platform, you can use [CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). You don't need to use it with S3, but you can.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Amazon AWS CloudFront for quick content delivery. Amazon CloudFront works seamlessly with any origin server, which stores the original, definitive versions of your files.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the [JQGrid CDN Link](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jqgrid)

http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jqgrid

Comment: I don't see any options for sign up.

Comment: "couldn't find version", "coulndn't feitch this", "couldnn't fetch that" -useless.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cloudflare](https://cloudflare.com). It will take care of all your JS CSS files, with added security to your whole system.