# Is there a CDN for jqGrid?

Tags: jqgrid, cdn

Anyone know if there is a CDN for [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)?

Thanks!

Comment: you can do it yourself, with [jare.io](http://www.jare.io), a free and instant CDN

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is [CDN for JQgrid](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jqgrid) ; not min version, though.

http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jqgrid

Once you get to the website, click on the Integration button and it will give you the JS code snippet you need to include to use the CDN.

Answer (score 1):

There's none that I could find, sorry.

You could take a look here: [Hosting Javascript/CSS file on CDN similar to Google hosting jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470981/hosting-javascript-css-file-on-cdn-similar-to-google-hosting-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can try submitting a request to http://www.jsdelivr.com

Comment: How reliable is jsdelivr.com?

Comment: I see that now they uploaded jqGrid onto jsdelivr, but it seems it's missing the minified full version jquery.jqGrid.min.js (the one that you obtain when running the jqGrid Download Builder):  http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jqgrid

Answer (score 0):

You could always link to the raw files on the Master branch at GitHub:

CSS: https://raw.github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css

JS: https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/tree/master/js

CSS is a clear win, but JS would need to include each individual module. That probably erodes the benefit of sourcing the include to an external site.

[update]

I wouldn't advocate doing this anywhere outside of development. In the long run, I think tools like Grunt/Bower are going to make CDNs less essential-unless you have multi-page apps.

Comment: Using github to serve css or js is terrible advice. If the author of the github repo makes any modifications, it could screw your entire site up. You really shouldnt be including from github in any way shape or form. The author could restructure the layout of his/her project, remove the project entirely, etc.

Plus github doesn't serve 'raw' files with it's expire headers far into the future, or with the correct headers. It'll be slower than serving from your own server.

Comment: @RickM I agree. This is only valid for development environments as a quick and dirty solution. Since GruntJS has become so solid, I no longer use CDNs at all. I can import my dependencies and concat them (safely) into a single vendor.js and vendor.css file.