# How to compress or reduce size of project in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, compression

I have a project which is simple CRUD operation with WCF, Entity Framework, Elmah error logging, Caching, MVC (View). Just one page. Now, I used Jqgrid and some javascript for that grid little. All good, but I am afraid the bin folder contains EF and Webgrisil which takes 2 MB and in the JQGrid, folder, some are around 4 MB.

Now my customer prefers the project (Prototype which I created) should be maximum 2-3MB. We can achieve it if we do not use maybe the jqgrid. But I am afraid I do not know other alternatives to do swiftly.

Now, the total project is 7.5MB without compression. How can I somehow compress it and send him? 7Z, Winrar and other compressors hardly help only 1 MB :( Is there anyway I can compress jQGrid as well as bin folder DLLs BUT should NOT disturb the working of the application.

Comment: Sorry, that seems like a totally ridiculous requirement to me. the size of the binaries are completely irrelevant. Much more so when talking about a Web application that's supposed to be deployed on a Web Server. Your customer either has no clue what .Net is / how it works or they simply have no clue at all.

Comment: @HighCore: Well sorry, now, it was a prototype, they want to see the code, they review it, but I was asked by my boss that, Customer mentioned it should be 2-3MB only maximum, which I can not slip by any means. I agree it is very much doable, by removing jqgrid, but do not know how to do normal jquery/javascript CRUD with a grid as I am new to this. They analyze my code and maybe give feedback on whether to proceed or not.

Comment: Well, this is all about communication. Discuss the facts with the customer (someone who understands why the restriction is actually in place). Perhaps they're only talking about the size of your code (or DLLs). If not, you can discuss how important the requirement is to them and why they want it so (and why you don't). It may be a valid requirement tied to web hosting limitations or it might be about the scope of the code review, but you won't know until you *ask*.

Answer (score 2):

I agree this seams like a very odd requirement.  However, if the jqGrid file is too large, use a copy that's hosted on a CDN:  [Is there a CDN for jqGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358316/is-there-a-cdn-for-jqgrid).  This way you'll be using jqgrid, but it won't actually be included in the delivered zip.

You can do this for your other 3rd party web sites.  If you can't find a mirror, upload them yourself.  For example, you could upload the file to a personal dropbox account and then get the public link, and reference the js / css files that way.

Comment: Let's be honest here - this is not an odd requirement, it is at best an ignorant requirement, or a miscommunicated requirement.